# grouping class names together in my CMS php

Tags: php, mysql

I am done with a CMS school system which i created from scratch for practice in php.  My question is for example I have Accounting 101, Computer Science 101,  however there must multiple times for Accounting 101.  For example:  Ticket 1035, 1036 are both Accounting 101 and they should appear in the same table, but in my code it shows them in different classes.  Here is my code.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $category = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM classes WHERE category_id = " . $category;
    $query2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query2))
    {
    ?>

    <center><h3><?php echo $row->class_name . '-' . $row->units; ?>  </h3></center>
    <table border ="0" wdith="100%">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <strong>Description: </strong>
    <?php echo $row->class_description; ?>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table border="1" width="44%">
<tr>
    <td width="60"><b>Ticket</b> </td>
    <td width="123"><b>Days</b></td>
    <td width="120"><b>Hours</b></td>
    <td width="64"><b>Room</b></td>
    <td><b>Instructor</b></td>
</tr>


    <tr>
    <td width="60"> <?php echo $row->ticket; ?> </td>
    <td width="123"><?php echo $row->days; ?></td>
    <td width="120"><?php echo $row->start_hours . $row->time_format . '-' . $row->end_hours . $row->time_format2 ;  ?> </td>
    <td width="64"> <?php echo $row->room_number; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->instructor_name;  ?></td>
</tr>
```

```
    }//end while

}//end if
```

Its showing Accounting 101 with different tickets in different tables, but it should be all in 1 table.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double loop if you're trying to get records inside of records.  For example:

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($query1))
{
  echo $row1->ParentName;

  $query2 = 'select * from `mytable` where `myForeignKey` = ' . $row1->ParentId;

  while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($query2))
  {
    echo $row2->ChildName;
  }
}
```

You could also do a left join.  Let me know if you need a sample of that.

Edit:

The left join would be done like this:

```
$sql = "select * from `classes` as a where category_id = '{$category}' left join `tickets` as b on a.id = b.class_id"
```

Ref.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Hi, could you please show me a left join example, that would probably be easier, thanks.

Comment: I tried that it did not work, here is what is in my classes table  
ID, category_id, ticket, class_name   syntax to use near 'left join ticket.  thanks

Comment: If you have "ticket" in your classes table, then how do you expect to have multiple tickets per class?  You have to have a separate table for "tickets."  Alternatively, you could store them as comma separated, but that may be too advanced for this implementation.

Comment: Here is what i mean there is 3 different tickent numbers but the under the same name Library 101http://secure.glendale.edu/schedules_ps/deptsched.asp?term=2127&type=&dept=LIBRARY

Comment: You must decide whether you are trying to link one record to one record or one record to many records.  This is known as 1 to 1 or 1 to many.  I think you are trying to do one to many.  In which case, you need to create another database table called "tickets" and foreign key that to your first table.

Comment: so I would create another table called tickets and make its id a foreign key, how would I do that? thanks so much, how would I implement "1 to many" relationship.  This is my first time dealing with LEFT joins and complicated queries, thanks for your patience.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14817/discussion-between-user1477388-and-masoman)